# Stuck with Node and Bower

Tags: node.js, bower, npm-install, bower-install

When I am giving npm install I am getting the below warning and it is not proceeding. It stuck in there.

```
npm WARN deprecated bower@1.8.0: ..psst! While Bower is maintained, we recommend Yarn and Webpack for *new* front-end projects! Yarn's advantage is security and reliability, and Webpack's is support for both CommonJS and AMD projects. Currently there's no migration path but we hope you'll help us figure out one.
```

Do anyone has any idea to proceed.

Comment: That's not the reason for it being stuck. It's just a deprecation warning, nothing too serious. You might have to wait a bit longer for NPM to finish installing.

Comment: Ya the issue is resolved ... I waited for nearly half an hour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I waited for half an hour and it works ... the issue got resolved